# bad performance of my CPU

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7

i have a intel i7 7500U CPU who have a maximum speed of 2,7 GHz but some day it suddenly start outperforming with everything (literaly), so my computer becomes unusable  so i decide to change mi Windows 10 OS to Linux mint in a way to at least understand whats happening with my PC.

After doing some research, I understand 2 things. First, the problem was because my battery is dead and my charger isn't the original. Second, i saw that when i start every application or open any tab in my browser the CPU speed decreces from 2 GHz (on average) to 400 MHz (on average).

So I install cpufreq, an app that allow me to manage my CPU speed but i doesnt improve to much (700MHz).

Help, I listen to easy fixes to force my CPU to work at least at the half of cappacity . please don't tell me that i need to buy another charger or battery I live in Chile and find this type of stuff (original) it's hard or have a very slow shipping

Comment: Have you checked airflow into the machine? Is the CPU fan working as expected? It sounds like some form of thermal throttling.

Comment: Your battery is dead, replace it, and at the same time replace the charger with a genuine charger.  There isn’t another solution to your problem, your problem, is caused by the battery